How can I get the status of a TON transaction and its information from the BOC with React?
I've successfully managed to initiate transactions on the TON blockchain using React. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to extract meaningful information from the BOC (Bag of Cells) that is returned after the transaction. Specifically, I'm unable to determine if the transaction was completed successfully.
What would be the right way to do it?
Problem
After sending a transaction, I receive a BOC string, and I'm struggling to parse it correctly to verify the transaction's status. I've attempted to use the loadTransaction method, but it throws an "Invalid data" error.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
            const tx = await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(myTransaction);
            const boc = tx.boc;
            const code_cell = Cell.fromBoc(Buffer.from(boc, 'base64'))?.[0]
            const txI = loadTransaction(code_cell.beginParse());
    


You can try:
const result: SendTransactionResponse = await tonConnectUi.sendTransaction(tx);
const cell = Cell.fromBase64(result.boc);
const buffer = cell.hash();
const hashHex = buffer.toString("hex");
console.log("Transaction Hash:", hashHex);


Please how can I retrieve the transaction details from the hash? I can’t seem to find where this information is specified.
